# How to downgrade Magento 2.3.3 to Magento 2.3.1 or 2.3.2

Tags: magento2.3, upgrade, magento2.2.7

I have upgraded my Magento from 2.2.7 to 2.3.3. But now, my Magento has so many issues. Is there any way to downgrade Magento 2.3.3 to 2.3.1 or 2.3.2?

Comment: previously how you updated ?

Comment: If I use the old version, I will be lost the new orders. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I would be interested to know some of the issues you are encountering. I'm having problems with emails but could be others I'm not aware of.

Comment: i guess you have outdated theme and extensions. the main problem in magento community - no one really understand how upgrade works.

Comment: @MagenX you could argue that the issue is that minor releases outdate themes and extensions.

Comment: @DominicXigen I have fixed some email issues. But I have some other issue can't be fixed.

Comment: @MagenX Magento has some issues with themself, it's not issue of theme or custom extension.

Comment: so first solution that came up in your mind is to downgrade?? not to list your issue here and try to understand what it is??

Comment: @David Duong please update your question with errors/issues you have

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can revert it back to Magento 2.3.1 or 2.3.2, Basically you need to just run following commands on command line.

For Version Magento 2.3.1

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.3.1 --no-update
composer update
```

For Version Magento 2.3.2

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.3.2 --no-update
composer update
```

For Version Magento 2.3.3

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.3.3 --no-update
composer update
```

For Version Magento 2.4.3

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3 --no-update
composer update
```

Then run all the following commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Or, if you want one line command from anywhere in your container/linux:

```
/bitnami/magento/bin/magento setup:upgrade ; /bitnami/magento/bin/magento setup:di:compile ; /bitnami/magento/bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f ; /bitnami/magento/bin/magento cache:clean
```

IF anything goes wrong, RESRART the docker container.

Comment: this is very bad idea...

Comment: I think it's worth explaining what the `--no-update` flag does

Comment: Thank bro. Do you ever do it?

Comment: Yes, I did this.

Comment: Great help. Thank you!

Comment: this would be the best solution. I did the same way and downgraded successfully

Answer (score 2):

downgrade = lots of security issues, database trashing, possible code mess, even more different problems.

if you have only production server - correct way is to create a backup before upgrade, then just jump back.

but if you dont have any backups, then fix all the issues - it will be much cleaner and easier to maintain later.

mashing code back and forth is a bad way.

Comment: Thank Bro. I have an issue is our store can't auto resize images, it only work on the main store.  Do you have any idea?

Comment: This is good standard practice. whenever we need to upgrade to newer version before doing this we should make all the backups.

Answer (score 2):

So in my case downgrading from Magento 2.4 to **2.3** would be

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.3.3 --no-update
composer update
```

Then run all the commands upgrade/static content deploy / di compilation and clear cache